# perlapio - PerlIO_findFILE() works but sets errno to "illegal seek" (ESPIPE 29)

Tags: c, perl, perl-io

This issue is more or less related to [embedded perl in C, perlapio - interoperability with STDIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549508/embedded-perl-in-c-perlapio-interoperability-with-stdio) which I think I have solved for the Windows environment. I will post a complete solution if this new issue is solved too.

In the linked question,
**StoryTeller** [gave me the hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549508/embedded-perl-in-c-perlapio-interoperability-with-stdio#comment70305613_41549508)
to use `PerlIO_findFILE()` which solved the immediate problem, but the same code on Linux behaves strangely.

Perl's `dup2()` seems to have a different behaviour on Win32, where `dup2()` is a macro for `win32_dup2()`, which as far as I understand simply uses the `dup2()` from `io.h` .

On Win32, Perl's version returns zero on success and non-zero on error, but on Linux the default ANSI `dup2()` will be used, which instead returns the new file descriptor. Then, I'll have to check `errno` if everything went fine.

If a call to `PerlIO_findFILE()` sets `errno` to "illegal seek" (errno 29 - `ESPIPE`), then after `dup`, `dup2`, `pipe` etc. `errno` is still set to "illegal seek", and any further checks on `errno` still see the same error.

(In practice everything has worked for me because there was no actual error. Also, the solution by checking `errno` is not thread safe, since between the syscall and the check another tread may reset errno.)

Note that I have

```c
#define PERLIO_NOT_STDIO 0
```

in effect and I'm using Perl5.14.1.

Am I doing something really wrong here?

Here's a simplified code snippet:

```c
stdOutFILE = PerlIO_findFILE(PerlIO_stderr()); // convert Perl's stdout to stdio FILE handle

fdStdOutOriginal = fileno(stdOutFILE);         // get descriptor

if ( fdStdOutOriginal >= 0 ) {

    relocatedStdOut = dup(fdStdOutOriginal);   // relocate stdOut for external writing

    if ( relocatedStdOut >= 0 )
    {
        if ( pipe(fdPipeStdOut) == 0 )         // create pipe for forwarding to stderr
        {
            // this has to be done on win32:
            // if ( dup2(fdPipeStdOut[1], fdStdOutOriginal)  == 0 ) // hang pipe on stdOut

            dup2(fdPipeStdOut[1], fdStdOutOriginal);

            if( errno == 0 ) {
                // do some funny stuff
            } else {
                // report error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `errno`'s value is only relevant if a function that sets `errno` failed. Functions aren't required to (and usually don't) reset `errno`. Also `errno` is required by POSIX to be threadsafe and mscvrt seems to define it that way too.

Comment: Re "*Functions aren't required to (and usually don't) reset `errno`*", They may even set it even if no error occur.

Comment: What is this `io.h` you mention?

Comment: @Karl: I had trouble following your post so I started to edit it. It has turned into a major revision, so please check that I have reflected your meaning properly. You're welcome to roll it back if you don't like what I've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`errno` is meaningless unless a C library call or a system call reports an error, so it can't be used to determine if an error occurred. Notably, these calls aren't required to (and usually don't) reset `errno` on success. It's not even safe to clear `errno` before the call, because the call may set `errno` even if no error occurred.

As best as I can tell, Perl's [emulation](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/443bd156a6baaf7a8fe6b6b05fcf6c4178140ed2:/util.c#l2826) of `dup2` returns the same value as the POSIX one (`-1` on error, `newfd` on success).

```
#ifndef HAS_DUP2
int
dup2(int oldfd, int newfd)
{
#if defined(HAS_FCNTL) && defined(F_DUPFD)
    if (oldfd == newfd)
        return oldfd;
    PerlLIO_close(newfd);
    return fcntl(oldfd, F_DUPFD, newfd);
#else
#define DUP2_MAX_FDS 256
    int fdtmp[DUP2_MAX_FDS];
    I32 fdx = 0;
    int fd;

    if (oldfd == newfd)
        return oldfd;
    PerlLIO_close(newfd);
    /* good enough for low fd's... */
    while ((fd = PerlLIO_dup(oldfd)) != newfd && fd >= 0) {
        if (fdx >= DUP2_MAX_FDS) {
            PerlLIO_close(fd);
            fd = -1;
            break;
        }
        fdtmp[fdx++] = fd;
    }
    while (fdx > 0)
        PerlLIO_close(fdtmp[--fdx]);
    return fd;
#endif
}
#endif
```

(From 5.24.1)

This means that we can detect an error in a platform-independent fashion, despite your claim to the contrary. As such, the proper usage is

```
if ( dup2(fdPipeStdOut[1], fdStdOutOriginal) >= 0 ) {
    //do some funny stuff
} else {
    //report error
}
```

Comment: good, so it has to be checked in the way you suggested - thank you. The only interesting thing is, that on WIN32, Perl's `dup2()` which in fact is win32_dup2(), indeed returns 0 on success and not the newfd. That's to keep in mind. But checking for `>= 0` does the trick anyway. (I'm using 5.14.1 btw.)